# java 9999-12-31 iso date inserted in mongo results as a non iso date inserted

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime, robo3t, isodate

I would like to insert the following document in mongodb:

```
 Query query = new Query();
 query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("client").is(client));
 Update update = new Update();
 update.set("dateTime", new DateTime());
 update.set("maxDate", new DateTime("9999-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00"));
 mongoTemplate.upsert(query, update, MyClass.class);
```

and the inserted object is

```
{
    "client" : "client",
    "dateTime" : ISODate("2020-03-12T10:11:35.077Z"),
    "maxDate" : Date(253402210800000)
}
```

I would like the maxDate to be in ISODate format. Is it possible ? 
Is **9999-12-31T00:00:00.000+01:00** too far for mongodb? 
Is there any issue with such a great value?

I read here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/shell-types/ that mongoDB could support year 9999

**EDIT with datagrip instead of robomongo usage**
if I use datagrip to read the documents instead of robomongo, the format is correct. Could the issue come from robomongo display?

Comment: MongoDB should work, i.e. `ISODate("9999-12-31T00:00:00")` works fine. Perhaps java does not support it, but I am not familiar with Java.

Comment: if I use datagrip to read the documents instead of robomongo, the format is correct. Could the issue come from robomongo display?

Answer (score 0):

I haven’t tried or run this. But I believe using a different constructor for DateTime should resolve this.. please try below constructor for maxDate field..

public DateTime(int year,
                int monthOfYear,
                int dayOfMonth,
                int hourOfDay,
                int minuteOfHour,
                int secondOfMinute,
                int millisOfSecond,
                DateTimeZone zone)

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but it doesn't help. In debug mode java side, I can see that both dates have the same format

Comment: i am looking at the long date you retrieved from the collection, it’s minimum long value of a date. It’s not just the format, the value is wrong. Have you tried traditional Date() & SimpleDateFormat() combo ?